# Could not find or load main class using Java in puTTY

Tags: java

I am currently tying to run a a java program on the puTTY shell but I cannot seem to get it to run. It will compile and make the correct class, but not run. How would I get it to find the main class and run correctly?

```
package project9;

import java.io.*;

public class Banker {
```

What I use to compile is:

```
javac Banker.java
```

What I use to attempt the run

```
java project9.Banker.class
```

or

```
java project9.Banker
```

both give the same results of not being able to find or load the main class.

Comment: is Banker contains 'public static void main(String args[]) {...}'?

Comment: Yes, further down in the code Banker contains the public static void main (String args[])

Comment: Can you run it without putty?

Comment: I've yet to try, for the assignment I need it to run in putty.

Comment: When you execute "javac Banker.java" I think you are standing at folder project9
 so you should go back out of the folder and execute java project9.Banker
It should work

Comment: Nope, it still just gave me the same error.

Comment: I think from the folder that you are standing, you should see:
`
- project9/Banker.java
and
- project9/Banker.class
 `
Could you make sure the structure?

Comment: If I were to use the 'ls' I do see the Banker.java and Banker.class.

Comment: If you use ls, you should see folder project9 only, please make sure about that. So you should cd back to a folder that contains folder project9

Comment: When I am outside of the folder that holds my 'Banker.java' and 'Banker.class' files and use the 'ls' command I do see my project folder, yes.

Comment: so does it work ?